# Why am I not seeing ARP requests from my own machine in wireshark?

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireshark, arp

I am using Windows 7.  I open up Wireshark and start a live capture with the filter: `ip.src == THIS.IS.MY.IP`

I then go to a command line and do an `arp -d *` and ping a bunch of stuff.

I see my ICMP traffic and other traffic in Wireshark, but no ARP traffic. Why is this?

I should mention with out the filter I do see ARP traffic coming from other machines on the network, just not my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARP traffic uses MAC addresses (Layer 2), not IP addresses (Layer 3), so your filter should be filtering out all ARP traffic.  Change your filter from `ip.src == MY_IP` to `arp` or `arp.src.hw_mac == MY_MAC` and you should see the ARP packets.

Comment: This works, looks like I was "lying" about not seeing any arp traffic from my machine with the filter off- I was sorting the traffic by destination and looking for my IP not my MAC.

Comment: To clarify, even though ARP requests _do_ contain IP addresses, they're in different fields – not in the (nonexistent) IP header, but inside the ARP request itself. So you'd need `arp.src.something` to filter by IP.